# JSON is null but data passes to success in ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm running into a problem in ajax. the scenario is: I would like to verify if the user is available or not when typing his email. So I create a function in javascript to do this with an Ajax script within it.
here my code :

```
$('#username').keyup(function () {
  var email = $(this).val();

  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://localhost:8080/MeublesTunisv4/web/app_dev.php/email-verification/' + email,
    dataType: "json",
    beforeSend: function () {
      $('#email_status').html('<img id="loading" src ="{{ asset('bundles/theme_front_end/images/loading.gif')}}"></img>');

    },
    success: function (data) {
      $('#email_status').remove();
      $('#email_status').html('<img id="loading" src ="{{ asset('bundles/theme_front_end/images/green_tick.png')}}"></img>');
    }

  });
});
```

my problem is : when I type any words it calls the function of keyup then it passes into success even if the data is null. I would like to let it pass to the success only if the data is correctly done. 
thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Following..Hope it works as you want...

```
$('#username').keyup(function () {
            var email = $(this).val();

           if(email != "") {

            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'http://localhost:8080/MeublesTunisv4/web/app_dev.php/email-verification/' + email,
                dataType: "json",
                beforeSend: function () {
                    $('#email_status').html('<img id="loading" src ="{{ asset('bundles/theme_front_end/images/loading.gif')}}"></img>');

                },
                success: function (data) {

                   // Check response data...
                   if(data == 'true') { 

                       $('#email_status').remove();
                       $('#email_status').html('<img id="loading" src ="{{ asset('bundles/theme_front_end/images/green_tick.png')}}"></img>');

                    }

                }

            });
         }

    });
```

Comment: I don't think `data` will *literally* be `"null"`, but rather a null-ish value such as an empty string. Otherwise, this answer is the same as mine.

Comment: Sorry for that...But i just assume that if no record found that response may be null or false (Any token)..

Comment: thank you #Nikhil it works but I modify a few code which is : if (data.email != null). my json is : { ' email ' : ' emailValue ' }. so I compare if the email is null or not . thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try some error checking before doing anything. Therefore, the `success` callback will be invoked (you cannot stop it conditionally), but the code inside will be prevented.

Encapsulate everything in the `success` event handler with the following so that it only executes if `data` is not null (empty string):

```
if(data != "") {
    // action here
}
```

I'm not sure what you mean when you say that "the data is null", so a simple empty-string conditional as shown above may not be sufficient to check whether or not the data is null. This will simply check if the `data` parameter is empty.

Comment: thank you lambda Ninja also you helped me to resolve the problem